# Edison's screen is stuck - no input from keyboard is recieved

Tags: keyboard, yocto, intel-edison

I've flashed an image with Preempt-RT on my edison, and for few days everything worked fine. Then, I connected rx to tx and continued working on my edison when suddenly edison got stuck.
Since then, for some reason edison's shell won't accept any input from my keyboard. I've re-flashed it a lot of times, also to a standard image(non-preempt-rt) and removed the connection between rx to tx, but it still doesn't work.
I also cannot do a "factory reset" because I cannot type, and thus I cannot press anything to go into autoboot.
I've tried to connect both from Ubuntu(12.04 and 14.04) and Windows(7), and in all the cases there is no option to type anything.
I've also tried to switch the cables and use other ones, but nothing works.

Yet I can see that edison does receive input, because I was able to flush an image to it, and it can deliver output because I see the output. 
So Maybe someone has any idea what kind of problem is this and what should I try to fix? Hopefully I will not have to buy another edison.

[image]

Comment: Did you check whether the keystrokes are really going out on the wire? (e.g. using an oscilloscope)

Comment: I didn't check with oscilloscope, but the keyboard works perfectly on other terminals (in Ubuntu) and in windows.
 In addition I've switched to other keyboard, and it had exactly the same effect- working on all I/O except for the edison terminal.

Comment: Are the LEDs (CapsLock, Num, etc.) on your keyboard working?

Comment: Yes, they are working.

Comment: So, can you press anything during U-Boot stage? If so, you might break the auto booting.